# Jquery datepicker weekends exclude from calcul

Tags: datepicker

How can i exclude weekends from min/max date calculation ?

Example : if the date is 15 oct , i can select only 5, 6 9, or 10 nov.

```
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
minDate: "+14D",
maxDate: "+19D",
```